# How to know when APCu cache gets cleared because it is full?

Tags: php, caching, callback, apcu

When APCu cache space becomes full, APC simply clears it off all its data so as to regain free cache space.

Is there a PHP way to know when this happens ?

Comment: Why should that be relevant? The cache data is recreated on the fly in a transparent way.

Comment: For house keeping and statistics. And potentialy to adapt some strategies in case cached value computation is heavy.

Comment: It might be interesting also to follow free space and trigger some event  in advance, when free space is statisticaly about to be missing soon.

Comment: OK, if you want to dive into that: what about the API APCu offers: nothing in there that might be useful?

Comment: Yes, asking for cache space and free space is ok with the API.

Answer (score 0):

Cache some dedicated cache tag ("cached" => "yes", longlastingvalidity)  and check whether its still there, or not.
When it's not there anymore : the cache has been flushed.